# Check length of Text Field - Custom Option

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options

For Magento 1.9 Product page, In custom option- text field, 
I try to list out the number of character for user-input on the text field, but with no success.

Comment: Thanks. But what i want is a text-counter that help user to know how many characters they have input.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not related to magento. It seems to be a question regarding javascript/jquery. You can try stackoverflow for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using jquery, please refer to below fiddle

```
    $('#mytextbox').keyup(function() {
    var cs = $(this).val().length;
    $('#characters').text(cs);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hNn5b/297/

Answer (score 0):

```
Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {
Element.insert( $('name').up().next().down('span'), { 
    'after': "<div id='name_counter'>Char count: <span id='name_counter_num'>"+(30-$('name').getValue().length)+"</span></div>"
});
 Event.observe('name', 'keyup', function(event) {  
    $counter = 30-$('name').getValue().length;
    $("name_counter_num").update($counter);   
});
```

});
Magento uses prototype.js by default so i am providing a code in prototype's format